# How to start emulator and install apk from terminal

Tags: bash, android-emulator

I wrote a bash file to start an emulator and install apk with the commands,
emulator -avd emulatorName 
adb wait-for-device
adb install OpenManager.apk 
but when i run the file from terminal it starts the emulator and it hangs there it doesn't execute the command to install the apk. But when i close the emulator then it execute the install command. Please, can someone help on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `&` to run the emulator process in the background:

```
emulator -avd emulatorName & adb wait-for-device && sleep 5 && adb install OpenManager.apk
```

and the `&&` to run the following command if the previous succeeded.

Comment: It has worked Thank you. All the commands has ran but it could not install the app with the following error message "Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?." I guess is because the device does not finish booting when the install command was executed. So please how can i use time to delay the execution of install command until the device finish booting?